# Invalid column index with SUM function and GROUP BY

Tags: java, sql

I have this exception (java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index) and I tried to solve it but it not work with me.

```
Jan 27, 2019 1:20:17 PM org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot processEvents
SEVERE: Error processing faces event for the component 
SearchIdeaForm:j_id_jsp_550475895_12
javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException: /Search.jsp(155,24) '# 
{searchIdeasBean.doSearchMyIdea}' java.lang.RuntimeException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:118)
at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:771)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:372)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:329)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.broadcastEventsForPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:304)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:261)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processApplication(AjaxViewRoot.java:474)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1152)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
at gov.adjd.iim.delegate.IIMDelegate.searchMyIdeas(IIMDelegate.java:325)
at iim.backbean.SearchIdeasBean.doSearchMyIdea(SearchIdeasBean.java:54)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
at org.apache.jasper.el.JspMethodExpression.invoke(JspMethodExpression.java:74)
at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:99)
... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
at im.dao.IIMDao.search(IIMDao.java:859)
at iim.delegate.IIMDelegate.search(IIMDelegate.java:320)
... 47 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getInt(OracleResultSetImpl.java:876)
at iim.dao.IIMDao.search(IIMDao.java:888)
at iim.dao.IIMDao.search(IIMDao.java:856)
... 48 more
```

This is my method that have the query:

```
public List<SearchResultDto> search(SearchDto searchDto, int userId) {

    Connection connection = null;

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet searchResultSet = null;

    try {
        connection = getConnection();
        String mainSql = "SELECT IDEA.I_ID,IDEA.I_NO,IDEA.I_TITLE,IDEA.I_DESCRIPITION,IDEA.I_CREATED_DATE,STATUS.S_DESCRIPTION,APPL_USER.U_NAME,SUM(EARNED_POINTS.EP_POINTS) AS TOTAL "
                + "FROM IDEA IDEA,STATUS STATUS,APPL_USER APPL_USER,EARNED_POINTS EARNED_POINTS "
                + "WHERE IDEA.I_STATUS_CODE = STATUS.S_CODE AND EARNED_POINTS.IDEA_ID = IDEA.I_ID "
                + "AND IDEA.I_CREATED_USER_ID = APPL_USER.U_SEQ AND EARNED_POINTS.USER_ID = ? AND IDEA.I_CREATED_USER_ID = ? "
                + "GROUP BY (IDEA.I_ID,IDEA.I_NO,IDEA.I_TITLE,IDEA.I_DESCRIPITION,IDEA.I_CREATED_DATE,STATUS.S_DESCRIPTION,APPL_USER.U_NAME,EARNED_POINTS.EP_POINTS)";

        if (searchDto.getIdeaNo() == null && (searchDto.getIdeaTitle() == null)
                && searchDto.getIdeaStatus() == null) {
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(mainSql);
            preparedStatement.setObject(1, userId);
            preparedStatement.setObject(2, userId);
        }


        searchResultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        return search(searchResultSet);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (searchResultSet != null) {
                searchResultSet.close();
            }

            preparedStatement.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

private List<SearchResultDto> search(ResultSet searchResultSet) throws SQLException {
    List<SearchResultDto> result = new ArrayList<SearchResultDto>();

    SearchResultDto searchResultDto = null;

    while (searchResultSet.next()) {
        searchResultDto = new SearchResultDto();

        searchResultDto.setIdeaId(searchResultSet.getLong(1));
        searchResultDto.setIdeaNo(searchResultSet.getLong(2));
        searchResultDto.setTitle(searchResultSet.getString(3));
        searchResultDto.setDescription(searchResultSet.getString(4));
        searchResultDto.setCreatedDate(searchResultSet.getDate(5));
        searchResultDto.setStatusDescription(searchResultSet.getString(6));
        searchResultDto.setIdeaCreator(searchResultSet.getString(7));
        searchResultDto.setPoint(searchResultSet.getInt(8));

        result.add(searchResultDto);

    }

    return result;
}
```

I know that there is small mistake in the query or where I get the searching result.

any comments!

Comment: I'm not sure, but you are making a group by and using another aggregation function with `EARNED_POINTS.EP_POINTS`. Is it possible?

Comment: @retatu the result of the query is right, it give me what I want when I test it in the SQL developer

Comment: Could you please post the whole stack trace from the Exception?

Comment: `java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index` is thrown when you try to `get` or `set` something from a resultSet and the index is not within the acceptable range. I can probably help you better with a stack trace.

Comment: @BiggusDikus I update the post

Comment: From the stack trace it is evident that the call to `searchResultSet.getInt(8)` is causing the exception.  Your query already has indexes 1 to 8. So the exception is strange!

Comment: Since you say that the query works in SqlDeveloper, the next place would be to attach a debugger and see what happens at the runtime. Perhaps set a breakpoint on `searchResultDto.setPoint(searchResultSet.getInt(8))` and see if you can evaluate `searchResultSet.getInt(8)`

Comment: It is a bit "strange" to include `EARNED_POINTS.EP_POINTS` both in `GROUP BY` and the aggregate function `SUM`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all.

this is the right answer, only I remove the (EARNED_POINTS.EP_POINT) from GROUP BY.

```
GROUP BY IDEA.I_ID,IDEA.I_NO,IDEA.I_TITLE,IDEA.I_DESCRIPITION,IDEA.I_CREATED_DATE,STATUS.S_DESCRIPTION,APPL_USER.U_NAME;
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution back. Was that original query working in SQLDeveloper with `EARNED_POINTS.EP_POINT` on `GROUP BY` clause?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the column count and its index is not appropriately returned in the result: So try this instead (get the columns count from resultsetmetatdata and use it to retrieve the columns from the row.)

```
ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData = rs.getMetaData();
int columnCount = resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount();
System.out.println("Number of columns : " + columnCount);

while (rs.next()) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++ ) {
      String name = resultSetMetaData.getColumnName(i);
      Object result1 = res.getObject(resultSetMetaData.getColumnLabel(i));
       //Integer result2 = res.getObject(resultSetMetaData.getColumnLabel(i), Integer.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing SUM on `EARNED_POINTS.EP_POINT` but you have the same column in your GROUP BY so just remove it from there.

```
GROUP BY IDEA.I_ID,IDEA.I_NO,IDEA.I_TITLE,IDEA.I_DESCRIPITION,IDEA.I_CREATED_DATE,STATUS.S_DESCRIPTION,APPL_USER.U_NAME;
```